# pypiserver: build_ext on mirror?

Tags: pip, pypi

We have a local pypiserver and up to now we are happy with it.

But psycopg2 makes trouble. It wants pg_config to be installed. I don't see a reason why it should be installed on the mirror server. I understand that it needs to be on the client where I install psycopg2.

Is this a bug in psycopg2? Or do I use the wrong options the get the package to the mirror?

```
pypi@gray:~> pip install --no-deps --no-install -d packages psycopg2
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  File was already downloaded packages/psycopg2-2.5.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2
    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info

writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: pg_config executable not found.



Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH

or specify the full executable path with the option:



    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...



or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/pypi/tmp/pip-build/psycopg2
Storing complete log in /home/pypi/.config/pip/pip.log
```

We use this pypiserver: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is over a year old but the answer is pg_config is a linux-only module. You would need to install postgresql-devel to get it.

Comment: We want to make the package available on our pypi-server. We don't want to install the package there. Why do you need postgresql-devel on the pypi server? I don't understand it.